# Get title of custom fields created by “Types” plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

Dealing with a large website I have more than 10 custom post types, around 400 custom fields for totally dynamic site grouped in 200 categories created with "Types WordPress plugin"

But when I am displaying data, i am using,

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
```

and by using this i am getting the sulg of custom field and the value. That means if my custom field name is "Bearing Code", i am getting `'wpcf-bearing-code'` and the value for it.

Is there any function to get the title of custom field created by types plugin, i.e.

```
function_name(wpcf-bearing-code)
```

would return me the value "Bearing Code". Manually I can do it, but it is not possible for more than 400 custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add below function in your current theme function file.

```
function get_fieldslable_pv($key) {
$wpcf_fields = get_option("wpcf-fields"); 
$key = str_replace("wpcf-", "", $key);
return stripcslashes($wpcf_fields[$key]['name']);
}
```

and now please use this function for your output.

```
echo get_fieldslable_pv('wpcf-bearing-code');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your site is big, call get_option to get all options with one sql request and then navigate in the array like below :

```
$fields = get_option('wpcf-fields');
$fields['wpcf-bearing-code']['data']['options'];
```